# Apache Kafka isolate different producers

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm working on a project where different producers (each one represented by another customer) can send events to my service.

This service is responsible for receiving those events and storing them in intermediate Kafka topic, later we are fetching and processing those events.

The problem is that one customer can flood events and effect processing of events of another customers, i'm trying to find a best way to create a level of isolation between different customers!

So far, i was able to solve this, by creating different topic for each customer.

Although this solution temporary solved the issue, it seems that Kafka is not designed to handle well huge number of topics 100k+ as our producers (customers) number grew up we started to experience that controlled restart of a single broker takes up to a few hours.

Can anyone suggest a better way to create level of isolation between producers?

Comment: you can have a single topic and partition on customer

Comment: @alirabiee i'm not sure that having 100k+ partitions is the right thing to do, am i wrong?

Comment: if your cluster setup can handle such a load, so does kafka

Comment: besides, the granularity of your partitions is independent of how you choose your key

Comment: @alirabiee amount of resources that will be required and overhead for zookeper is huge compared to using 1 topic with x partitions, i don't believe that is the right design, i thought maybe split customers to some kind of baskets creating y topics will scale better...

Comment: Current Kafka design (0.11) uses a single-point-of-failure controller to manage partition allocations, when that controller broker dies it gets re-elected, but during that time re-elections are not possible. Kafka 1.+ is supposed to scale better.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Kafka limits, that is done on Kafka broker level. By configuring producers to have different user / client-id each, you could achieve some level of limiting (so that one producer does not flood others).

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_quotas

Answer (score 1):

With the number (100k+) that you mentioned I think that you will probably need to solve this issue in your service that sits before Kafka.

Kafka can most probably (without knowing exact numbers) handle the load that you throw at it, but there is a limit to the number of partitions per broker that can be handled in a performant way. As usual there are no fixed limits for this, but I'd say the number of partitions per broker is more in the lower 4-figures, so unless you have a fairly large cluster you probably have many more than that. This can lead to longer restart times as all these partitions have to be recovered. What you could try is to experiment with the *num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir* parameter and set this higher, which could bring your restart times down.

I'd recommend consolidating topics to get the number down though and implementing some sort of flow control in the service that your customers talk to, maybe add a load balancer to be able to scale that service ..